# Connect a router to a switch to use wifi

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, switch

My laptop is connected to a switch (more then 24 pc) with a wire.

I would like to be able to use my laptop everywhere.

I bought a wireless router (d-link) and connected the wire to the wan port, but since I don't access to any shared device (e, f, g etc).

Do i need to connect the wire to the wan or lan port?

Do i need to enable dhcp on this router?

Comment: If you want DHCP then you will need to replace the switch with the router.  More information about the network would be required to provide more information.

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. You should rewrite your question. It is badly written and needs a spellcheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your wireless router is not going to be the main firewall for your network then you can do the following:

1. Configure the wireless router with a static IP address.  So if your home network is 192.168.1.X give the router a static IP along the lines of 192.168.1.250 (making sure that no other device on your network has the same IP address)
2. Turn DHCP **off** on the wireless router
3. Configure the SSID and security settings you want for your wireless connection
4. Plug the cable that you were using for your laptop into one of the **LAN** ports on the router
5. At this point your laptop should see the wireless router and you should be able to connect to it using the credentials you specified in step 3 and have internet access.

**Assumptions**:

- Your current firewall/modem is handing out DHCP